# Шифрование? Биты? КОдировка?

Tags: кодировка

Столкнулся с проблемой, имеется чек на котором есть штрих код, при считывании получаю вот такой код 023DC58D95E. Помогите определить в каком формате этот код? или какие то данные может содержит? какая кодировка? Что то совсем ума не приложу. Прилагаю скан чека с информацией. Пишется программулька, для внесения чеков в базу, просто чек человек уносит с собой и данные хранятся на чужом сервере, делается локальная база, для сверки в дальнейшем с основной, но если это какая то кодировка, незнаю что с ней делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это может быть все что угодно. может это вообще ID записи об этом чеке в БД системы и никаких конкретных данных из чека не содержит

Comment: Обычно такие ШК это просто внутренний код записи в БД, может контрольная сумма документа... т.е. смысловой нагрузки для вас не несет, только для тех кто данный чек "создал"

Comment: 16- ричный, какой-то хеш скорее всего, 02 3D C5 8D 95 E - но не хватает одного символа

Comment: Я вот тоже думал 16-ричный.....с вашими мнениями согласен, но мало ли, как говорится своей головы не хватает, нужно больше голов)))

Comment: @NewView Почему именно "хеш" ? Любые данные могут быть записаны в шестнадцетиричном виде. И почему "не хватает буквы", никто не сказал, что объем данных должен быть кратен 8и битам.

Comment: Для 16 код не подходит, если не хватает цифры

Comment: @NewView Еще как подходит. Одна буква кодирует 4 бита, вот и все. Если вам надо закодировать 44 бита то будете использовать строку именно такой длины, что бы не писать лишнего нуля.

Comment: @Mike но все же как тогда перевсти в человекочитаемый вид и понять что там содержится?)

Comment: @Qunn обратится к разработчикам и спросить у них скрытый смысл послания.... но мне кажется уже понял что там закодировано... я почти на 100% уверен что там `42`. Вы просто посмотрите, если посчитать контрольную сумму чека, сложить ее с числом со штрихкода поделить результат на ноль, отнять бесконечность прибавить 4 раза по 10, затем еще прибавить 2 - получим искомый ответ!! `42`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не вариант, базу никто не даст, это франшиза, поэтому локально свое придумываем, скажи свои 100% )))

Comment: Майк, в чем смысл не писать лидирующий ноль? Как это парсить? Или эта вещь сама в себе? тогда возможно

Comment: @NewView Но это же содержимое штрихкода, если писать ведущий ноль то это еще куча черточек, которые могут на чек не влезть. И может ведущий ноль тут вообще ни к чему, может последние 4 бита это контрольная сумма от предыдущих данных. А может тут вообще первые 3 бита значат номер кассы, следующие 2 бита номер смены и т.п. и так набирается именно 44 бита, зачем писать лишнее, если значащих данных нет. А с декодированием вообще никаких проблем. шестнадцетиричка же по одному символу отлично переводится в биты

Comment: Ну вещь сама в себе, без внешнего интерфейса так сказать :) я об этом и говорил. Глянуть чего получается `=Åà` полная ерунда. (псевдосимволы съел редактор)

Comment: Это номер товара по базе, чисто случайное число, мое мнение :) смысла в нем нет, просто случайный Guid() или хеш с названия + номер записи, например.

Comment: @Qunn По одному чеку вы все равно ничего не поймете. берете сотню чеков, выписываете все значащие данные и шрихкод. Далее ищете закономерности. Если повезет, то может будет какая то зависимость, типа первая цифра даты 1 - и на опред. позиции в коде определенные биты. Если видите, что минимальные изменения на чеке ведут к полностью дригим битам всего штрихода, то скорее всего перед вами хеш (или шифр) с хорошим лавинным эффектом и вы из него все равно ничего не получите

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ага, поделить на ноль доставило ^_^ ну в общем значит можно закрывать тему....значит результата не добиться